# Dotted line persists after deleting comments

Tags: bug

After deleting all comments on a post, the line which separates comments from the main post remains.

See this screenshot (from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/347506/how-can-we-get-the-command-line-of-a-running-application?noredirect=1#comment460141_347506)) and note the dotted line after the post which shouldn't be there for posts with no comments:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this happens because I was using a link to one of the old deleted comments to access the question (and have provided that link as the example above), thus generating that dotted line. Accessing the normal question works.